# MySQL options file connect to remote servers without typing password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have a `[client]` option group with my local credentials for my database, which lets me quickly access my database from the CLI.

Can I set something up the same way in this file so that I can access the databases for my production databases or development databases - hosted on different servers - so I don't have to remember or lookup the credentials or hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional configuration files using the same format then reference the alternate config files with a command line option.

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=prod.cnf
```